# Send error message via background job in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to send an error from a pl/sql script that I can log and monitor.

I try to create a procedure that does nothing but fail and display a custom defined error meassage.

```
PROCEDURE Custom_Error ()      
BEGIN
  raise_application_error(-20101, 'Custom Error!');
END Custom_Error;
```

I'm not allowed. I get this error:

```
Compilation errors for PACKAGE ...
Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:
```

My plan was to call this procedure in the background, and then get the error 'Custom error' in my log of background jobs in error.

Is this the right way to go about this?

BR

Comment: you do not need any `()` after a proc name. but why not just call `raise_application_error`  where you what to call `Custom_Error ` ?

Comment: try removing the `()` after the procedure name. They're not needed if your procedure (or function) has no parameters.

Comment: If I do:

    PROCEDURE Custom_Error
    BEGIN
    raise_application_error(-20101, 'Custom Error!'); 
    END Custom_Error;
I get this error:
Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY KC_PROD.KOSAN_KC_API
Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: ( ; 
       The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.

Comment: A quick glance as the PL/SQL documentation confirms that [create procedure headers are separated from the rest of the code by AS or IS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/procedure.htm#LNPLS01336).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax for a parameterless procedure in PL/SQL

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Custom_Error is      
BEGIN
  raise_application_error(-20101, 'Custom Error!');
END Custom_Error;
```